# Prevent nvidia-docker from installing nvidia drivers with debian package

Tags: docker, driver, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I am trying to create an nvidia-docker image with installed TensorRT for my specific application. I can't use any of the provided TensortRT base images, as they are using CUDA version not compatible with the application, but I have a custom TensorRT debian package which is used in my organization. The problem is, when I install it from the Dockerfile, it also installs nvidia drivers. As a result, the container is successfully created, but can't be started - the result is:

```
svc_moma_usr@PL1LXD-529389:~/gutkowsp/Docker_projects/test_cuda$ nvidia-docker run tensorrt-test
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"process_linux.go:432: running prestart hook 1 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: mount error: file creation failed: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/97f449ff2535b1ad304520dae75c613931888658a66b89235b0d040a872a625c/merged/usr/bin/nvidia-smi: file exists\\\\n\\\"\"": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

The dockerfile is:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.1-devel-ubuntu16.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV CUDNN_VERSION 7.0.5.15
LABEL com.nvidia.cudnn.version="${CUDNN_VERSION}"

RUN apt update -y && \
    apt install software-properties-common -y && \
    apt-add-repository --yes --update ppa:ansible/ansible && \
    apt install ansible -y

RUN apt update -y && \
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libcudnn7=$CUDNN_VERSION-1+cuda9.1 \
    libcudnn7-dev=$CUDNN_VERSION-1+cuda9.1

RUN apt update -y && \
    apt install tensorrt -y
```

How this problem of unnecessary drivers is solved? This seems to me like a common issue, as in general nvidia docker images typically have installed nvidia software, which usually comes with drivers. Maybe someone can share the dockerfiles for the TensorRT images for reference?

Comment: Have you tried `RUN apt install <driver-I-want>` before all the other apt installs?  There's a chance the install system will see you have satisified the pre-requisite of havking an nvidia driver of some kind and not replace it.  Or is the driver you don't want in `nvidia/cuda:9.1-devel-ubuntu16.04` ?

Comment: No, I have not checked installing driver before other installs. But I am not sure how that would help. I do not want to install nvidia-driver at all, since if it is installed, the system won't use the host driver. It is not about replacing driver in the container.

Comment: When I was using plain docker (not nvidia-docker) to isolate a cryptocurrency GPU miner, I found that the docker container needed an nvidia driver.  Details [here](https://gist.github.com/DrPaulBrewer/a8a976f24036c81f1777ef457e6d71ea).  I seem to recall that in this configuration both the host and the container needed the driver.  The host needed it so that the `/dev/nvid*` files would exist on the host and could be forwarded to the container.  I'm not sure why the container needed it, but it did.  Of course, this may omit other things nvidia-docker is handling for you, but was much earlier.

Comment: And, to answer your earlier question, whether pre-installing a driver will help depends on how the internal package is set up.  If the internal package uses a virtual prereq that can be satisfied by multiple alternative actual packages, then preinstallling is useful and will satisfy the virtual prereq.  Linux packages sometimes use explicit pre-requisites, and sometimes "virtual" ones.  A virtual pre-req can be satisfied by various alternatives.   A common use case involves requiring the user to have *some* text editor, or web browser, but not requiring a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who facing the same issue:

1. If necessary use CUDNN enabled docker image, like `11.7.1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu18.04` to avoid the necessity to install it using apt
2. Run `apt update`
3. Run `apt install <your package> -y --dry-run | grep nvidia`
4. Add all listed nvidia packages to apt ignore list - add a dash after the package name with an asterisk in place of version number

   ```
   apt install <your package> libnvidia-compute-*-server- \
   libnvidia-compute-*- --dry-run | grep nvidia
   ```
5. Make sure that none of nvidia packages will be installed. If necessary add newly discovered packages to ignore list.
6. If everything is OK then remove --dry-run flag and install your package

   ```
   apt install <your package> libnvidia-compute-*-server- libnvidia-compute-*-
   ```